# How to fix "Maximum update depth exceeded.calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate." error in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, debugging, npm

The code was working fine but this came out of nowhere.

I tried switching the condition over to `componentDidMount` but that didn't work either. Getting the error on this function.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (
      this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser &&
      this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile &&
      !this.state.userProfile
    ) {
      this.setState(
        {
          userProfile: this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile
            .userProfile
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

It is supposed to be redirecting the user to the nextPage but gives me an error of "Maximum update depth exceeded".

Comment: `this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile.userProfile`, do you have a `userProfile` inside `currentUser.userProfile` ?

Comment: From docs -> `You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition`  Your condition needs to be comparing with `prevProps`..  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have .userProfile.userProfile? You're likely updating userProfile with undefined, so it's failing your `!this.state.userProfile` check.

I would remove the second .userProfile.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `prevProps` to the `componentDidUpdate` and then using that within your conditional. Without more info about why you're using userProfile, I'd suggest doing something like below:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser === this.prevProps.firebase.auth.currentUser) {
   ///your code
}}
```

Your logic for the `this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile && !this.state.userProfile` seems like it should not be located in this method, as it seems redundant if you are comparing whether the `currentUser` is still there and the same after the component updated.